# How to identify properties of a concave diffraction grating

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, experimental-technique

As a little side project I want to build a spectrometer. The main components are an entrance slit, a concave diffraction grating and a CCD sensor (also the electronics). I bought a used diffraction grating online and now I am trying to figure out the needed dimensions of the device. The grating came with a datasheet (Horiba - 532 00 570) but it only specifies:

- groove density = 1200 1/mm
- spectral range = 350 - 850 nm
- blaze wavelength = 450 nm
- dimension 42.4$\times$42.4 mm

On their site they say that the grating is actually designed for a monochromator but I read that that it should also work with a CCD sensor (if tilted correctly). I already contacted Horiba and they only sent me the data sheet which I already have.

How do I find out which distance has to be between entrance and grating, grating and the sensor, what angle should be used between the two arms, as well as the tilt of the sensor in respect with the diffracted beam? I experimented quite a bit and have a setup that works (meaning I have a focused spectral line on the sensor which still fits on it), but I would like to be more precise.